# Why the “auto” value of “cursor” gives my anchor a text-like cursor

Tags: css, mouse-cursor

Documentation of `auto` value says

> The UA will determine the cursor to display based on the current context. E.g., equivalent to text when hovering text.

```css
a {
  cursor: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com">hover your mouse over me</a>
```

Why the above style-sheet gives me an I-beam for a link? I expected a `pointer`-like cursor because that’s for an anchor tag right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That description is based on CSS Level 2 Revision 1 (a.k.a. CSS 2.1). In [CSS Basic User Interface Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#valdef-cursor-auto) (a.k.a. CSS3 UI) the description became:

> The UA determines the cursor to display based on the current context, specifically: `auto` behaves as `text` over selectable text or editable elements, and `default` otherwise.

This is more explicit. Note that CSS3 UI is already a *recommendation* (the term for “standard” in web industry).